# PIL Image, cut from one image to another

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to cut a section from one image and paste it into another.  I'm using the following code:

```
img1 = Image.open("Img1.png")
img2 = Image.open("Img2.png")
cut = img2.crop((31, 0, 47, 15))
cut.save("cut.png")
img1.paste(cut, (150,300))
img1.save("NewImg1.png")
```

When I look at `cut.png` I see the right part cut out. However when it's pasted into img1, the resulting image just has a black box where the pasted section should be.

I suspect this may more be an issue with my images than the code, (both were created in Paint.NET, saved with default options) but I don't really know where to look right now to figure out the problem.

Comment: Have you tried saving AFTER the paste?  I can't imagine why it would matter but that's my first guess.  Also, is either image transparent anywhere?

Comment: Moving `cut.save` to the end (I assume that's what you mean) has no effect on either.  
And, yeah, img2, the one being cut from, has transparency, which I suspect is something to do with the problem.